# Classification model produces extremely low test accuracy, although training and validation accuracies are good for multiclass classification

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do alphabet classification for American Sign Language. So it's multiclass classification task with 26 classes. My CNN model gave 84% training accuracy and 91% validation accuracy, yet test accuracy is hilariously low - only 7.7% !!!

I used `ImageDataGenerator` to produce training and validation data:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=0.2,
        width_shift_range=0.05,
        height_shift_range=0.05,
        shear_range=0.05,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest',
        validation_split=0.2)

img_height = img_width = 256

batch_size = 16 
source = '/home/hp/asl_detection/train'

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    source,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='training', # set as training data
    color_mode='grayscale',
    seed=42,
    )

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    source,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='categorical',
    subset='validation', # set as validation data
    color_mode='grayscale',
    seed=42,
    )
```

This is my model code :

```
img_rows = 256
img_cols = 256

def get_net():

    inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, 1))
    print("inputs shape:",inputs.shape)

    #Convolution layers
    conv1 = Conv2D(24, 3, strides=(2, 2), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    print("conv1 shape:",conv1.shape)
      
    conv2 = Conv2D(24, 3, strides=(2, 2), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    print("conv2 shape:",conv2.shape)
    
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    print("pool1 shape:",pool1.shape)
    
    drop1 = Dropout(0.25)(pool1)

    conv3 = Conv2D(36, 3, strides=(2, 2), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(drop1)
    print("conv3 shape:",conv3.shape)

    conv4 = Conv2D(36, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    print("conv4 shape:",conv4.shape)
    
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    print("pool2 shape:",pool2.shape)
    
    drop2 = Dropout(0.25)(pool2)

    conv5 = Conv2D(48, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(drop2)
    print("conv5 shape:",conv5.shape)
    
    conv6 = Conv2D(48, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    print("conv6 shape:",conv6.shape)
    
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv6)
    print("pool3 shape:",pool3.shape)
    
    drop3 = Dropout(0.25)(pool3)

    #Flattening
    flat = Flatten()(drop3)

    #Fully connected layers
    dense1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(flat)
    print("dense1 shape:",dense1.shape)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)

    dense2 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(drop4)
    print("dense2 shape:",dense2.shape)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)

    dense4 = Dense(26, activation = 'softmax', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(drop5)
    print("dense4 shape:",dense4.shape)
            
    model = Model(input = inputs, output = dense4)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.00000001, decay=0.0)

    model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

This is training code :

```
def train():
    
    model = get_net()
    print("got model")
    model.summary()

    model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('seqnet.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    print('Fitting model...')
    
    history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = 100)
    
    # list all data in history
    print(history.history.keys())
    # summarize history for accuracy
    plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    # summarize history for loss
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show() 
    
    
    return model

model = train()
```

This is training log for last few epochs:

```
Epoch 95/100
72/72 [==============================] - 74s 1s/step - loss: 0.4326 - acc: 0.8523 - val_loss: 0.2198 - val_acc: 0.9118
Epoch 96/100
72/72 [==============================] - 89s 1s/step - loss: 0.4591 - acc: 0.8418 - val_loss: 0.1944 - val_acc: 0.9412
Epoch 97/100
72/72 [==============================] - 90s 1s/step - loss: 0.4387 - acc: 0.8533 - val_loss: 0.2802 - val_acc: 0.8971
Epoch 98/100
72/72 [==============================] - 106s 1s/step - loss: 0.4680 - acc: 0.8349 - val_loss: 0.2206 - val_acc: 0.9228
Epoch 99/100
72/72 [==============================] - 85s 1s/step - loss: 0.4459 - acc: 0.8427 - val_loss: 0.2861 - val_acc: 0.9081
Epoch 100/100
72/72 [==============================] - 74s 1s/step - loss: 0.4639 - acc: 0.8472 - val_loss: 0.2866 - val_acc: 0.9191
dict_keys(['val_loss', 'loss', 'acc', 'val_acc'])
```

These are the curves for model accuracies and losses:

[image]    [image]

I didn't use `ImageDataGenerator` to prepare test data, unlike training and validation data. For test data, I used `OpenCV` for converting images to grayscale, further I did normalization. In the same loop I generated the corresponding label of the image to prevent any order mismatch. I saved the image file names and labels in a csv file. Here's the code:

```
source = '/home/hp/asl_detection/test/unknown'
files = os.listdir(source)
test_data = []
rows = []
for file in files:
    
    row = []
    row.append(file)
    row.append(file[6])
    print(file)
    row.append(ord(file[6]) - 97)  
    rows.append(row) 
    
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(source, file))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(256, 256))
    test_data.append(img)
    
test_data = np.array(test_data, dtype="float") / 255.0
print(test_data)
print(test_data.shape)

with open("/home/hp/asl_detection/test/alpha_class.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Here are few tuples of the csv:

[image]

Further I reshaped the test image array to give channel information:

```
test_data = test_data.reshape((test_data.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1))
```

Finally predicted classes and calculated accuracy on test data by fetching labels from csv:

```
y_proba = model.predict(test_data)
y_classes = y_proba.argmax(axis=-1)
data = pd.read_csv('/home/hp/asl_detection/test/alpha_class.csv', header=None)
original_classes = data.iloc[:, 2]
original_classes = original_classes.tolist()
y_classes = y_classes.tolist()
acc = accuracy_score(original_classes, y_classes) * 100
```

Could you plz find the reason behind such a low test accuracy? If any information is needed further, plz let me know.

Comment: Maybe you are overfitting?

Comment: Hi, the model wasn't overfitting.The problem was somewhere else.

I'll post the updated code later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing an overfitting problem and the validation set misleads you. For the validation not to be misleading it has to have the same distribution of the test set, so try to generate the test and validation sets from the same distribution, also don't do data augmentation with the validation data set.

Comment: Hi, the model wasn't overfitting.The problem was somewhere else. I agree on this -  "try to generate the test and validation sets from the same distribution, also don't do data augmentation with the validation data set."

I'll post the updated code later.